# Firebase array item is removed and immediately auto-added back (with AngularFire)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to remove an item from $firebaseArray (boxes).

The remove funcion:

```
function remove(boxJson) {
        return boxes.$remove(boxJson);
    }
```

It works, however it is immediately added back:

[image]

This is the method that brings the array:

```
function getBoxes(screenIndex) {

        var boxesRef = screens
            .child("s-" + screenIndex)
            .child("boxes");

        return $firebaseArray(boxesRef);

    }
```

I thought perhaps I'm holding multiple references to the firebaseArray and when one deletes, the other adds, but then I thought firebase should handle it, no?

Anyway I'm lost on this, any idea?

**UPDATE**

When I hack it and delete twice (with a timeout) it seems to work:

```
function removeForce(screenIndex, boxId) {

        setTimeout(function () {
            API.removeBox(screenIndex, boxId);
        }, 1000);

        return API.removeBox(screenIndex, boxId);
    }
```

and the API.removeBox:

```
function removeBox(screenIndex, boxId) {

        var boxRef = screens
            .child("s-" + screenIndex)
            .child("boxes")
            .child(boxId);

        return boxRef.remove();
    }
```

Comment: How do you construct your array? It may be that something is keeping your array in sync ie making sure it always has that element

Comment: The array comes from the server. I used $firebaseArray. I found the problem - a bug on my part, was saving the items after deleting them. oops. Thank you for your comment Akhaku.

Answer (score 1):

When you remove something from firebase it is asynchronous. Per the docs the proper way to remove an item is from firebase, using AngularFire is:

```
var obj = $firebaseObject(ref);
obj.$remove().then(function(ref) {
  // data has been deleted locally and in the database
}, function(error) {
  console.log("Error:", error);
});
```

> $remove() ... Removes the entire object locally and from the database. This method returns a promise that will be fulfilled when the data has been removed from the server. The promise will be resolved with a Firebase reference for the exterminated record.

Link to docs: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-remove

Comment: Thanks. I've added a callback. It says it was deleted successfully and yet it is recreated again.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that **you have a security rules that disallows the deletion**.

When you call `boxes.$remove` Firebase immediately fires the `child_removed` event locally, to ensure the UI is updated quickly. It then sends the command to the Firebase servers to check it and update the database.

On the server there is a security rule that disallows this deletion. The servers send a "it failed" response back to the client, which then raises a `child_added` event to fix the UI.

Comment: after investigating I realised that when I delete twice (with a timeout) it does delete so it must allow this. I added the code as an update to the question.

Comment: Most likely you're having a race condition with adding the item and deletin git. But having to add code like that to a question is a sign that you should first reproduce the problem in a minimal way. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way we'll be able to help you more efficiently than working from an incomplete repro from a complete app.

Comment: You're right. It would be easier, i'll try and create a MCVE. It will take some time, it's quite a large project and the boxes array is the backbone of that data structure.

Comment: Found the problem, clearly my mistake. I was saving the elements which were deleted later on when clearing the selection. What should I do with the question?

Comment: I'll vote to close as a type/non-reproducible. It is unlikely that someone in the same situation will find this question with their search terms (unknown unknowns and such).

Comment: Ok, what is the difference between closing and deleting? I can delete it

Comment: I think deleting it is more severe. But I actually don't know. I think closing is best here, although it would actually be better if you answer it showing the code that was causing the problem. Especially with some well picked words, it might be findable and help someone in the future after all.

Comment: Done. added the answer. Thank you Frank.

Answer (score 1):

Appearantly I was saving the items again after deleting them. Clearly my mistake:

```
    function removeSelected(boxes) {
        var selectedBoxes = Selector.getSelectedBoxes(boxes);

        angular.forEach(selectedBoxes, function (box) {

            BoxManager.remove(box);

        });

        Selector.clearSelection(boxes, true);
    }
```

In the clearSelection method I was updating a field on the boxes and saved them again.

Besides the obvious mistake this is a lesson for me on how to work with Firebase. If some part of the system keeps a copy of your deleted item, saving it won't produce a bug but revive the deleted item.

Answer (score 0):

For those, who have the similar issue, but didn't solve it yet.

There are two methods for listening events: `.on()` and `.once()`. In my case that was the cause of a problem. 
I was working on a migration procedure, that should run once

```
writeRef
    .orderByChild('text_hash')
    .equalTo(addItem.text_hash)
    .on('value', val => { // <-- 
        if (!val.exists()) {
            writeRef.push(addItem)
        }
    });
```

So the problem was exactly because of `.on` method. It fires each time after a data manipulation from FB's console.

Changing to `.once` solved that.